# First line not capitalizing correctly in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of every name in a file, so I wrote the following code:

```
with open('C:/Users/Nishesh/Documents/updated_firstnames.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as updated_fnames_file:
    with open('C:/Users/Nishesh/Documents/capitalized.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_fnames:
        for line in updated_fnames_file:
            new_fnames.write(line.capitalize())
```

I'm new to Python, so I'm well aware that this is probably poor formatting/logic (and I'd appreciate suggestions to improve it), but for my purposes, this did manage to correctly capitalize every item in the file other than the very first one, as far as I can tell. Actually, the first name in the original file was already capitalized, but after I ran this it ended up lower case in the resulting file. The other items in the first file which were already capitalized were not made lower case however - just this one. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post your input, your expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

capitalize() :

> It returns a copy of the string with only its first character capitalized.

You probably need capwords() from string lib.

string.capwords() :

> Split the argument into words using str.split(), capitalize each word using str.capitalize(), and join the capitalized words using str.join().

Or you can do the same method by hand

```
new_fnames.write(' '.join(map(str.capitalize, line.split())))
```